# Jmeter Run Thread Groups Consecutively vs No of Threads

Tags: jmeter

What is the difference between following Jmeter test architectures?

```
--Test Plan(Run Thread Groups Consecutively not checked)
    --Thread Group 1(No of Threads(users) : 1, Ramp up Period(in Seconds) : 1, Loop count: 1)
    --Thread Group 2(No of Threads(users) : 1, Ramp up Period(in Seconds) : 1, Loop count: 1)
    --Thread Group 3(No of Threads(users) : 1, Ramp up Period(in Seconds) : 1, Loop count: 1)
    --Thread Group 4(No of Threads(users) : 1, Ramp up Period(in Seconds) : 1, Loop count: 1)
    --Thread Group 5(No of Threads(users) : 1, Ramp up Period(in Seconds) : 1, Loop count: 1)
    --Thread Group 6(No of Threads(users) : 1, Ramp up Period(in Seconds) : 1, Loop count: 1)
    --Thread Group 7(No of Threads(users) : 1, Ramp up Period(in Seconds) : 1, Loop count: 1)
    --Thread Group 8(No of Threads(users) : 1, Ramp up Period(in Seconds) : 1, Loop count: 1)
    --Thread Group 9(No of Threads(users) : 1, Ramp up Period(in Seconds) : 1, Loop count: 1)
    --Thread Group 10(No of Threads(users) : 1, Ramp up Period(in Seconds) : 1, Loop count: 1)

--Test Plan(Run Thread Groups Consecutively not checked)
    --Thread Group 1(No of Threads(users) : 10, Ramp up Period(in Seconds) : 1, Loop count: 1)

--Test Plan(Run Thread Groups Consecutively not checked)
    --Thread Group 1(No of Threads(users) : 2, Ramp up Period(in Seconds) : 1, Loop count: 1)
    --Thread Group 2(No of Threads(users) : 2, Ramp up Period(in Seconds) : 1, Loop count: 1)
    --Thread Group 3(No of Threads(users) : 2, Ramp up Period(in Seconds) : 1, Loop count: 1)
    --Thread Group 4(No of Threads(users) : 2, Ramp up Period(in Seconds) : 1, Loop count: 1)
    --Thread Group 5(No of Threads(users) : 2, Ramp up Period(in Seconds) : 1, Loop count: 1)
```

In my scenario, I want to do load test of my solution where I have different test cases executed by different users. Here users have a very little chance to do same operation at a time. So I use different thread groups for my test cases. And with my scenario increase **No of Threads(users)** in thread group doesn't mean logical to me. So I unchecked **Run Thread Groups Consecutively** in my Test plan but not sure about does it really makes a concurrency test or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check **Run Thread Groups Consecutively** then thread groups will fire up consecutively.That means JMeter will start Thread Group 01 first, then Thread Group 02 ,......, and so on. It's an option here to instruct JMeter to run the **Thread Groups** serially rather than in parallel.

So if you unchecked **Run Thread Groups Consecutively** in your Test plan, it will make a **concurrency** in your test.

Comment: Yeah I know that. If I increase No of threads then same test will also run multiple times in parallel. Whats the difference between these two??

Comment: The basic difference is  when "Checked"  **Run Thread Groups Consecutively** then JMeter will execute the Threads in the **First Thread Group** and end the test and then start the next thread group and execute those threads in that thread group  and so on..

Comment: oh no no I don't mean that. If I uncheck Run Thread Groups Consecutively it will run threads in parallel. On the other hand if I increase No of Threads in a thread group it will also start multiple users in parallel. Whats the difference between these two?

Comment: Please take a look to my 1st and 2nd test plans. Whats the difference between these two?

Comment: **Run Thread Groups Consecutively** is only applicable when you use multiple **Thread Groups**.

Comment: Look as per my knowledge, if I use 10 thread groups and uncheck Run Thread Groups Consecutively then 10 threads will run in parallel. Additionally, if I use 1 Thread group with No of threads 10 then also 10 threads will run in parallel. I don't find any difference here and that make me suspicious about my knowledge.

Comment: For the first case , 10 threads from 10 different Thread Groups will run parallel. But if you use one thread group and under this you use "No of Threads(Users) = 10", then this 10 thread will not initiate at the same time. It totally depends on the **Ramp Up** time you provided for those 10 threads under one thread group.If you put Ramp up time =10 second ,then those 10 threads will up within 10 seconds.If you set the value as "1 second" then those 10 threads will be innitiated within 1 second. It solely depends on the **Ramp Up Time** you give.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111342/discussion-between-tanjim-rahman-and-adnan).

Answer (score 2):

In **case 1** you are guaranteed to have a concurrency of 10 threads right from the start of execution.

In **case 2** the concurrency of 10 threads is reached after 1 second, with rate of 1 thread per 100ms (provided no threads finished their execution within that time).

**Case 3** mixes both options: 5 threads will start immediately, and 5 more after 1 sec, so the concurrency of 10 threads is reached after 1 second.

Note that when I say "concurrency reached" I mean on JMeter side. Depending on the setup of the script, concurrency for the server may be reached later.

What's also important is that you have "**Loop count: 1**". If all users run that single loop iteration for a long time (minutes/hours), or there's a loop controller inside the thread group, the difference between 3 options is insignificant for statistics. But if that iteration is short (seconds to a few minutes), or each operation within each thread is unique, then in case of options 2 and 3 (especially 2), your statistics will be flawed, since many operations on threads that started earlier will be performed before 10 thread concurrency is reached and vice versa.

Comment: For case 2 why 9 seconds?

Comment: @TanjimRahman: each thread will start 1 second after previous thread, so first thread will start immediately, second thread will start after 1 second, third thread will start after 2 seconds, and so on; thread 10 will start after 9 seconds. So after 9 sec you will have 10 threads running

Comment: But as per [link](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html); for case 2 10 threads should start within 1 second.

Comment: ok, for some reason you have delay `10` in second case (i.e. 1 second per thread). But yea, with 1 sec in total the delay is barely noticeable (100ms per thread)

Answer (score 1):

JMeter acts as follows:

- For each Thread Group it starts threads during "ramp-up" period
- Threads start executing samplers upside-down or according to [Logic Controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers)
- When thread doesn't have a sampler to execute or loop to iterate - it's being shut down

So you can run into a situation where 1st thread has already finished everything and was shut down and 10th thread hasn't been started yet.

If you want to have guaranteed concurrency - provide enough loops at [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level. You can also use i.e. [Ultimate Thread Group](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) which has some extra features to flexibly define users arrival rate and visualise anticipated concurrency.

By the way, you can get different virtual users executing different scenarios even in the same Thread Group using [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller). See [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) article for detailed explanation of the possible approaches.